# I have an application i want to generate 3d models in canvas, but i dont know which tool to use

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js

User selects multiple options and depending on it the application generates 3d model.

Comments:
1. It's must be canvas.
2. Models must be generated on live, not stored in database because there can be millions of them.

What have I came up to:

1. Looks like threejs almost fits my needs, but all my experience is toying with webgl and canvas renderer. I have a background in 3d so its not a problem. I don't know can threejs generate 3d models onlive using canvasrenderer? I'm not talking about particles or spheres or smth, my  models are complicated. Threejs doc is good, but there are a lot of blank spaces. Intuition tells me to do something with dynamically creating Object3d and fill it with geometry and vertices but I haven't find any manual or example how to do it.
2. Maybe, I can have some sketch models in collada and then modify them via threejs?
3. Maybe there is another library?
4. Maybe I should face impossibility and use flash?

Thank you, stay cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly general question, so it's kind of hard to answer, but I think, basically, that YES, Three can probably do the job you're looking for. For example, are you thinking about doing something like this:

http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/machines/#

?

And, BTW, yes, you'd probably do a lot of Object3D creation and loading into the scene. You might well want to start with some small, predefined models that get loaded into the scene and then modified. If it looks like what you're after, try taking the google sketch apart and understanding it.

Comment: Generally, it's not exactly what am i looking for, but anyway, these sources are much more useful, than threejs doc. Lot of thanks!